# How to generate multiple orders from cart in Hybris storefront?

Tags: e-commerce, shopping-cart, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm working with Hybris 6.3 we generated a module for a B2B implementation  and I have the requirement of splitting the cart contents into different orders depending on the products in the cart, the billing address, payment, delivery, etc must share the same parameters.

From the requirements we've gathered from our client, we concluded applying consignments strategies aren't what we requiere here, since that handles one order and splits it for shipping and delivery purposes, instead our client's needs are that the different products in the cart to be grouped by a set of shared attributes and generate an order for each group of products.

So far I have identified the class in charge of placing the order in the storefront extension, **DefaultCheckoutFacade**, which contains the following method:

```
 @Override
 public OrderData placeOrder() throws InvalidCartException
 {
     final CartModel cartModel = getCart();
     if (cartModel != null)
     {
         if (cartModel.getUser().equals(getCurrentUserForCheckout()) || getCheckoutCustomerStrategy().isAnonymousCheckout())
         {
             beforePlaceOrder(cartModel);
             final OrderModel orderModel = placeOrder(cartModel);
             afterPlaceOrder(cartModel, orderModel);
             if (orderModel != null)
             {
                 return getOrderConverter().convert(orderModel);
             }
         }
     }
     return null;
 }
```

From what I understand, I should override this method to generate a different **CartModel** accordingly to the criteria set in my requirements and place an order for each **CartModel**. I revised the **CartModel** class, and it's superclass **AbstractOrderModel**, I'm guessing after the *getCart()* call in the method above, I just need to modify the entries in the **CartModel** and make a call to the method *placeOrder()* for each order I need to place, but is it allowed to modify the **CartModel** object in this way?

Or if I need to split my cart into different orders, should I approach this in a different way? Is something like having multiple carts but showing them as one something that should be done? Does this kind of modification should be done on the OOTB commercefacades extension? Is there a way to extend it somewhere in our module?

**EDIT**

I started to read about [Multiple Carts](https://help.hybris.com/6.2.0/hcd/4d094e78a5494963b2d66148167f0553.html) and it seems to be what I need, but I haven't found how to save entries to a saved cart. In [this link](https://help.hybris.com/6.2.0/hcd/8b85a20586691014bacda05068f9c842.html) I can see how to save the cart, the method *saveCart* returns a **CommerceSaveCartResultData** object, both *saveCart* and the method *getCartForCodeAndCurrentUser* receive a **CommerceSaveCartParameter** which must contain a CartModel, how can I generate an instance of this object to set in a **CommerceSaveCartParameter**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I identified that my approach was completely wrong from the beginning, the order splitting shouldn't be done neither generating multiple carts nor using consignments, both were the wrong choices all along.

Since the requirement is for multiple orders  to be sent to ERP, and DataHub is the one in charge in doing it in my client's case, the two extensions that required to be extended were: **[saporderexchange](https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/8c4eba5886691014b781f7c9f299194d.html)**, **[saporderexchangeb2b](https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/8c4ee52186691014bdefc69ea48e6ac0.html)** and **[ysaporderfullfillment](https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/8c94cd8086691014ad00da13fd3740e8.html)**.

First I created a **customsaporderfullfillment** extension from the ysaporderfullfillment template, then I had to change the *executeAction* method in **SendOrderToDataHubAction** to split the Order generated from Hybris, accordingly to the criteria set:

```
@Override
public Transition executeAction(final OrderProcessModel process) throws RetryLaterException
{
    LOG.info("Executing Send Order To DataHub Action");
    final OrderModel order = process.getOrder();
    List<SendToDataHubResult> results = new ArrayList<>();
    List<AbstractOrderEntryModel> entries = order.getEntries();
    Map<String, List<AbstractOrderEntryModel>> sortedEntries = sortEntries(entries);
    final Object[] keyArray = sortedEntries.keySet().toArray();
    LOG.info("Number of Orders to generate: " + keyArray.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < keyArray.length; i++)
    {
        // Clone the order
        String newOrderCode = generateOrderCode();
        LOG.info("Generated Order Code " + newOrderCode);
        OrderModel clonedOrder = getOrderService().clone(null, null, order,
                newOrderCode);
        LOG.info("Cloned order.");
        String key = keyArray[i].toString();
        LOG.info("Setting entries for Key: " + key);
        final List<AbstractOrderEntryModel> entriesForCart = sortedEntries.get(key);
        clonedOrder.setEntries(entriesForCart);
        LOG.info("Sending Order to DataHub");
        sendOrder(clonedOrder, results);
    }

    if (!results.isEmpty() && results.stream().allMatch(result -> result.isSuccess())) {
        LOG.info("All Orders were sent successfully.");
        setOrderStatus(order, ExportStatus.EXPORTED);
        resetEndMessage(process);

        return Transition.OK;

    } else {
        LOG.info("Not all Orders were sent successfully.");
        setOrderStatus(order, ExportStatus.NOTEXPORTED);
        handleRetry(process);

        return Transition.NOK;
    }

}
```

Then I had to extended the saporderexchangeb2b extension with my own customsaporderexchangeb2b extension, I had to create a CustomB2BOrderContributor that would do the mapping into the RawHybrisOrder attributes I required:

```
@Override
public Set<String> getColumns()
{
    final Set<String> columns = super.getColumns();
    columns.addAll(Arrays.asList(CustomOrderCsvColumns.SALES_ORGANIZATION, CustomOrderCsvColumns.DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL,
            CustomOrderCsvColumns.DIVISION, CustomOrderCsvColumns.DOCUMENT_TYPE));
    LOG.info("Columns present " + columns.size() + " : " + columns.toString());
    return columns;
}

@Override
public List<Map<String, Object>> createRows(final OrderModel model)
{
    final List<Map<String, Object>> rows = super.createRows(model);
    return enhanceRowsByCustomB2BFields(model, rows);
}

protected List<Map<String, Object>> enhanceRowsByCustomB2BFields(final OrderModel model, final List<Map<String, Object>> rows)
{
    // There is only one row on order level
    final Map<String, Object> row = rows.get(0);
    final String salesArea = ((HelvexProductModel) model.getEntries().get(0).getProduct()).getSalesArea();
    final String[] valuesArray = salesArea.split("_");
    final String salesOrganization = valuesArray[0];
    final String distributionChannel = valuesArray[1];
    final String division = valuesArray[2];
    LOG.info("Enhancing columns of Order " + model.getCode() + " with Sales Organization : " + salesOrganization
            + ", Distribution Channel : " + distributionChannel + ", Division : " + division);
    row.put(CustomOrderCsvColumns.SALES_ORGANIZATION, salesOrganization);
    row.put(CustomOrderCsvColumns.DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL, distributionChannel);
    row.put(CustomOrderCsvColumns.DIVISION, division);
    row.put(CustomOrderCsvColumns.DOCUMENT_TYPE, Config.getParameter("helvex.org.sales." + salesOrganization));
    row.put(CustomOrderCsvColumns.MOTIVE, sessionService.getAttribute(CustomOrderCsvColumns.MOTIVE));
    LOG.info("Enhanced rows " + row.toString());
    return rows;
}
```

Since RawHybrisOrder is missing the mapping in saporder-raw, saporder-canonical and saporder-target, I had to add the attributes I added to the rows in raw and canonical, finally I overwrote the target definition of the iDoc to be sent so the attributes I mapped in the canonical were used instead of the standard mappings.

Now you'll say, what about the Hybris order generated? That one is not displayed to the storefront since the Orders we show are retrieved from ERP, not the Hybris database.

Answer (score 3):

The common approach for this functionality it's using OOTB [Order Splitting](https://help.hybris.com/6.5.0/hcd/8c21e59786691014bb0add90a5a3d52b.html) feature (`DefaultOrderSplittingService`) for split your order into `OrderEntryGroup`. Example from Hybris documentation:

```
<bean id="orderSplittingService" class="de.hybris.platform.ordersplitting.impl.DefaultOrderSplittingService">
<property name="modelService" ref="modelService"/>
<property name="consignmentService" ref="consignmentService"/>
<property name="strategiesList">
    <list>
        <ref bean="splitByDeliveryMode"/>
    </list>
</property>
```

Strategy implementation:

```
    public class SplitByDeliveryMode extends AbstractSplittingStrategy
{

    @Override
    public Object getGroupingObject(final AbstractOrderEntryModel orderEntry)
    {
        return orderEntry.getDeliveryMode();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterSplitting(final Object groupingObject, final ConsignmentModel createdOne)
    {
        createdOne.setDeliveryMode((DeliveryModeModel) groupingObject);

    }

}
```

If you really need to clone Orders you can customize `SubmitOrderStrategy`, `DefaultOrderService` and use `CloneAbstractOrderStrategy`

Comment: Consignments aren't what we need here, the items in the cart need to be grouped by the criteria defined in our business logic and generate an order for each group of items with the same criteria, I need to split the items in the cart into different orders, not to split an order into consignments.

Comment: Why are you so fixed on cloning the order? Splitting into consignments is exactly what you should do here. You can define the criteria how to split the order very flexible. Its not just for delivery mode or warehouse purposes.

Comment: Each group of items in the cart need to generate an order, not cloning it

Comment: @UrielArvizu : You should go with consignment split only. It will help you to make the things easier. You can write your custom Strategy to split your order into consignment based on products in the cart, the billing address, payment, delivery etc.

Comment: The thing is, consignments aren't the same thing as Orders, the Orders are sent to ECC from our client, Consignments inherit from ItemModel directly, and lack the information an Order does, plus ECC then sends iDocs with Orders, so that is the main reason for not using consignments.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use multiple cart. When user click checkout button with his wants, you can create new cart with out of list, then remove them from cart and go to process it. Because there is alot of calculation over cart, if you don't split as two cart, coupon and rules can be give to customer extra fees because of whole products.

Comment: I haven't used multiple cart, does each cart generate a separate order? Do you have a link to the documentation?

Comment: Found [this link](https://help.hybris.com/6.2.0/hcd/4d094e78a5494963b2d66148167f0553.html) and I think I could create carts from the main cart I display to the user each filled with the entries grouped by the shared criteria, but haven't found how to add entries to an instance of this carts, any suggestions?

Comment: @UrielArvizu there cartService for adding items to carts. You need development for moving items between carts.

Comment: But I need to generate a CartModel to pass to the CommerceSaveCartParameter for the saveCart, right? Any idea how to create an instance of that?

Comment: I check the DefaultCartService, and indeed it has the method you mentioned but it receives a CartModel, how can I generate new CartModel instances?

Comment: You can use modelservice create metod.

Comment: Oh and I can even clone the cart for it to have the same properties and just modify the entries in the cloned cart? What about modifying entries in the cart? Should I use **DefaultCartService**? I can see that class has a deprecated *addToCart* method, should i use that one on a cloned cart with no entries to add the grouped ProductModels?

Comment: If functionality not enough on defaultcartservice you can extend it. You can use CommerceAddToCartStrictStrategy for adding items on it. You can check DefaultCommerceCloneSavedCartStrategy for cloning carts. If it is not enough you can extend it.

Answer (score 1):

We had a quite similar requirements. Our strategy was to use SplittingService as suggested before, and override CloneAbstractOrderStrategy to convert consignments to OrderModel (or SubOrderModel). It can be complex since you would have to manage the calculation of your orders and so on properly but it can be achieved using this approach.